# Does he "has" or "have" store key?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. Does he has store key?
> 2. Does he have store key?

Please tell me which one is correct. Also, please explain briefly difference between 'have' and 'has' and when they are used.

Comment: Are these your own creations? Or did you find them in a textbook, exercise book, etc? Please provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), and if possible, include your personal thoughts on the matter.

Comment: First, you need a determiner like "a" or "the" before "store key". The answer is that "have" is correct. In your example "does" is an auxiliary verb which obligatorily requires the following verb to be an infinitive, in this case the infinitive verb-form "have". Since the requirement is for an infinitive verb-form, the question of whether to use either of the tensed forms "has" or "have" does not arise.

Comment: @BillJ, maybe you should post your comment as an answer.